# Using PHP to do a subrequest on the same server

Tags: php, html, rest

I have an existing REST application on my server.
For example, if you send a request with the DELETE method to "/users/3" it will delete the user whose id is 3.

But now I would like to create an HTML "client" for this application. For example there is an HTML form, and when you submit it the user is deleted.
Unfortunately you can't write `<form method="delete" action"/users/3">` because only GET and POST are supported by forms. And even if you could, I would like the user to be redirected to a "the operation successed" or a "there was an error" page afterwards, which would not be possible.

I considered using AJAX, but I need to support the [insert injurous comment here] people who deactivated Javascript

I could modify the application so I can send POST requests with `method=DELETE&redirect=/successpage&redirectfail=/failpage` but that would take a lot of time.

Is there a way to send the POST request to a PHP page, which would in turn translate it to the real request, then would interpret the status code returned by my app, and do the appropriate redirection?

Thank you

EDIT: I'm not using any framework for the app. This was a very simple app at the beginning, and it became more complex over time

Comment: Are you using a framework for you PHP application? Which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a [CURL request](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to your REST API:

See the `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` option:

> A custom request method to use instead of "GET" or "HEAD" when doing a
>   HTTP request. This is useful for doing "DELETE" or other, more obscure
>   HTTP requests. Valid values are things like "GET", "POST", "CONNECT"
>   and so on; i.e. Do not enter a whole HTTP request line here. For
>   instance, entering "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" would be
>   incorrect.

For example:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');    
curl_exec($ch);
```

So this would be actioned in the target file of the form after the form has been POSTed onto it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PHP's HttpRequest::send to do that. You cannot send it directly via a form but you can write a PHP-script for that in respond to sending the html-form.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.httprequest-send.php

Comment: This would be using the `HTTP_METH_DELETE` constant for the method.

Comment: Thanks, I'm accepting the cURL answer because it comes with PHP

Answer (score 2):

Be **VERY** careful - doing self-requests can lead to deadlocks when using file-based sessions. The parent script will load/lock the session, then do the sub-request to another script, which attempts to start the session itself. The parent script has locked the session, so the subrequest will hang until the session becomes available... but the session will never become available because the parent is waiting for the subrequest to complete.

Comment: Assuming this is a RESTful app, the state (session) lives only in the client.

Comment: nikc is right, I'm using HTTP authentification. Thanks for the information anyway, I wouldn't have thought about it. I forgot to talk about it, but this is another argument for not using form to send POST requests

Answer (score 0):

Why not just: `<form method="post" action"/users/3">` which would send the request to the custom page (the information is being sent in the action rather than in the POST). The 'delete' is from your /users/3.

Answer (score 0):

You could POST to /users/3 but in your form include a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
```

Then in your scripts you can just check to see if it exists and is delete and run it the script accordingly. The nice thing about this method is that it becomes easy to add "put" as well, since you just change the value in the form.